# R - connecting to SQL Server using using RSQLServer

Tags: r, rsqlserver

I want to use RSQLServer instead of RODBC to connect to a database called 'Mkt_DW'. I think my server hostname is my machine DHX number - that's what is returned when I query the hostname in SQL Server 2008 using:

```
SELECT HOST_NAME() AS HostName, SUSER_NAME() LoggedInUser
```

I then enter the following code into R Studio:

```
library(RSQLServer)
library(DBI)
driver <- dbDriver("SQLServer")
url <- "DHX32510;Database=Mkt_DW;Trusted_Connection=TRUE;"
conn <- dbConnect(driver, url)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in rJava::.jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", url,  : 
  java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,

Neil

Answer (score 0):

It is because it cannot find the 'sql.yaml' file:

See not from the package author:

*"See ?SQLServer. It will look for the YAML file in the following location by default: Sys.getenv("HOME")"*

https://github.com/imanuelcostigan/RSQLServer/issues/57

Comment: I don't think your answer is relevant. Find the differences: (from your linked GitHub issue) `java.sql.SQLException: Unknown server host name 'AW'.` (from the question) `java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect`.